# whitespace after image

Tags: css

I am learning on how to work with CSS. Currently, I am trying to learn about CSS positioning. I use different background color for each div section, so I know which area of the page that gets affected when I make code changes.

I am working right now on my header page and stumbled into one thing that I do not understand. I have a logo and put it inside its own div. The problem that I can see, below the logo there is a whitespace (i use pink background color for the div) and I cannot get rid of it. So below is the code that I use and the screenshot of what the header looks like currently.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Print Repair Form</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    * {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
      font: 12px/1.5 Georgia, serif;
    }

    #page-wrap {
      width: 800px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #header {
      background-color:#88d;
      overflow: auto;
    }

    #logo {
      float:left;
      background-color: #ffccff;
    }

    #logo a img {
      border:none;
    }

    #address-container {
      display: table;
      float: left;
      width: 164px;
      background-color: #FC730A;
      height: 104px;
    }

    #address-content{
      display:table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }

    #repair-header {
      background-color:#d4d4d4;
      float:left;
      width:380px;
    }

    #customer-info {
      float: left;
      width:220px;
      background-color: #ffff99;
    }

    #wo-info {
      background-color: #99ff99;
    }

    #content {
      clear:both;
      background-color:#33d;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="page-wrap">
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="/fms/"><img src="/fms/images/windows8-cropped.jpg" /></a>
      </div> <!-- div logo -->
      <div id="address-container">
        <div id="address-content">
          456 Some Addresses <br />
          The City, XP 444411 <br />
          1-800-000-0000 <br />
          www.someaddress.com
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="repair-header">
        <p>Repair Detail</p>
      </div>
      <div id="customer-info">
        <p>12345678</p>
        <p>Facility Name</p>
      </div>
      <div id="wo-info">
        <p>WO: 12345789</p>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- div header -->
    <div id="content">
      <p>Content is here</p>
    </div>
  </div> <!-- div page-wrap -->
</body>
</html>
```

[image: web-header]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the property

```
line-height: 0;
```

to your logo div

```
#logo {
  float:left;
  background-color: #ffccff;
  line-height: 0;
}
```

and modify your image css to:

```
#logo a img {
  border:none;
  vertical-align:bottom;
}
```

Comment: I added that code but still not working. I viewed the webpage using IE9 and Firefox 16.0.2

Comment: You're right, I just modified my answer and tested it in IE9. Works. After scratching my head for a while, I got that answer from here about the bottom align. http://askthecssguy.com/articles/inline-images-showing-a-gap-of-space-on-the-bottom-and-one-way-to-get-around-it/

Comment: I ended up using display: block inside #logo a img. Using vertical-align:bottom messes up my other divs.